# find all the equilibrium points for $x'=y^3-4x$ , $y'=y^3-y-3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider the system

$x'=y^3-4x$

$y'=y^3-y-3x$

What is the systemic way to find all the equilibrium points for this system?

My approach is to set both $x'$ and $y'$ to $0$ , solve the two equations and I find that $y=x...$ However, not all $x$ and $y$ work for $x'$ and $y'$ which equal $0$ ?

Is this a right way to solve it?

Comment: got it thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve the system
\begin{align}
y^3-4x&=0\\
y^3-y-3x&=0.
\end{align}
From the first equation $y^3=4x$, substituting into the second one you obtain $4x-y-3x=0$, that is, $x=y$. Substituting back into the first equation you obtain 
$$
x^3-4x=0.
$$
So $x_1=0, y_1=0$, $x_2=2, y_2=2$ and $x_3=-2, y_3=-2$.